# Laravel Nova field BelongsToMany drilling down the data

Tags: laravel, has-and-belongs-to-many, laravel-nova

I am developing a Web Application using Laravel. I am using Laravel Nova for building the admin panel. But I am having an issue with BelongsToMany field.

I have the database schema as follow

```
Area

Station - has area_id because an area has many stations

manager - area_id because each user belongs to an area

Area_station - station_id and manager_id (many to many)
```

So in the Station nova resource, I added a field like this.

```
BelongsToMany::make('Managers', 'managers', Manager::class),
```

Therefore, when I go to the Station details page from the Nova admin panel and select "Attach manager", in the dropdown of the next page (page to attach a manager to the department), I can see all the available managers in the database.

But instead of displaying all the available managers in the drop down, I like to filter the managers/users which belongs to the same area as the selected Station. I mean when I attached a manager to the Station, I have to select a station. Is it possible to filter or to achieve what I want in Nova?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `relatableQuery` function which will determines which instances of the model may be attached to other resources, under `Manager` nova resource.

***Approach 1***

```
public static function relatableQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    // In case manager is get attached to another resource except Station. 
    if ($request->resource() == 'App\Nova\Station') { 
        $station = $request->findResourceOrFail();
        return $query->where('area_id', $station->area_id);
    }

    return parent::relatableQuery($request, $query);
}
```

**Update**

***Approach 2*** - Learned something new just now.

You can add a relatable query for  the relationship under `Station` Nova resource. In this case no need to check for the resource.

```
public static function relatableManagers(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $station = $request->findResourceOrFail();
    return $query->where('area_id', $station->area_id);
}
```

Approach 2 is better in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @samuni it is working. But not Approach 2. So I used Approach 1. Cheers.

Comment: Ahh. I don't know why it was not working for me. I will give it a go again when I get the chance. Thanks man.

Comment: Make sure to place the relatable<Model>() function in the requesting resource. In the example of the original question function relatableManagers needs to be added in the Station resource file. This is opposite of the relatableQuery function which needs to be added in Manager resource.